# What is the difference between Windows 8 Pro and Windows 8 Pro Pack?

Tags: windows-8, upgrade

The Microsoft Store has two version of Windows 8: Windows 8 Pro, and Windows 8 Pro Pack:

[image: store]

What is the difference between these versions of Windows 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows 8 Pro allows you to upgrade from an **older** version of Windows (XP, Vista, 7) to Windows 8 Pro.

Windows 8 Pro Pack allows you to upgrade from a **lesser version of Windows 8** to Windows 8 **Pro**.

The Windows 8 Pro Pack is just license to move a Windows 8 installation to Windows 8 Pro with Media Center. **It does not contain any physical media**.

> [The Windows 8 Pro Pack](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbpage.Windows_8_Pro_Pack) enables you to move up to Windows 8 Pro. Your
>   PC or tablet must be running Windows 8 to use Windows 8 Pro Pack. The Pro
>   Pack makes your PC or tablet ready for business by adding
>   professional-grade features by adding:
>
> - **Encrypt your data with BitLocker:** BitLocker drive encryption helps protect corporate data on mobile PCs that include a TPM chip.
>     BitLocker now encrypts hard drives more quickly, helping to keep your
>     data safe without interrupting your productivity. BitLocker now
>     supports encrypted drives, too.
> - **Stay safer with SmartScreen:** SmartScreen services help protect you from malicious sites and software on the Internet. It checks the
>     reputation of any new app or website, helping to keep you safe no
>     matter what browser you're using. That helps prevent malware and other
>     viruses from infiltrating your PC, or your corporate network.
> - **Connect to company networks with DirectAccess:** Just because you're not in the office doesn't mean you're not working. DirectAccess allows
>     remote users to more securely and seamlessly access resources inside
>     of a corporate network without having to launch a separate virtual
>     private network (VPN) connection.
> - **Windows Media Center:** Windows Media Center lets you turn your PC into a home entertainment system that can play and record
>     high-definition TV (if you have additional tuner hardware), DVDs, and
>     CDs. It's also a software DVR that can play photo slideshows and
>     Internet TV content.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Matthew said, Windows 8 Pro does not come with the **Windows 8 Media Center Pack**, while **Windows 8 Pro Pack** does.